# Tink - streaming encryption with Hashicorp Vault as KMS

Tags: tink

I'm trying to use Tink, and I've successfully encrypted a file using streaming AEAD. I've also integrated Tink with Vault and performed encryption for a single message. However, I couldn't find an example of how to utilize streaming capabilities with Vault as a KMS. Could you please assist me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct method within the current framework to accomplish this task. However, a potential solution is detailed in this issue:  https://github.com/tink-crypto/tink-go/issues/8